# How to calculate the timezone of these data?

Tags: r, python-2.7, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a very large dataset with customer feedback, and I want to remove duplicates.

The feedback looks like this:

```
Great service!, n days ago
OK, n days ago
Could be better, n days ago
Awesome, n days ago
YES!, n days ago
```

To get the timestamp of each feedback, I subtracted `n days ago` (e.g. `5 days ago`) from the time the file was downloaded to my computer (e.g.  `2015-07-06 EST - 5 days = 2015-07-01`).

The problem is that I don't know the timezone of the server I downloaded from, i.e. when the feedbacks were recorded, so some identical feedbacks from the same customer are recorded twice. The server has since been shut down and is inaccessible to me.

Example:

```
Feedback, Timestamp
Great service!, 2015-07-05 00:00
Great service!, 2015-07-04 02:00
OK, 2015-04-07 09:00
OK, 2015-04-06 17:00
Could be better, 2015-08-08 01:00
Could be better, 2015-08-07 13:00
Awesome, 2015-07-10 03:00 
Awesome, 2015-07-09 19:00   
YES!, 2015-03-20 03:00 
YES!, 2015-03-19 13:00
```

Assuming there is no way to obtain the timezone from the server, is there a way I can calculate the timezone, based on the data I present over here? I can't figure it out, so I hope someone out there can help!

Comment: Why language tags have been removed?

Comment: @Pascal how is the question related to a language? Why not C++, Perl?

Comment: @helloV It is the choice of the OP, you cannot go against this choice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult in this case to conclusively say that a comment is a duplicate. If you are willing to treat identical 'Feedback' as a duplicate, you can use `dplyr` as follows to filter the first row:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Feedback = c('Great service!', 'Great service!', 'OK', 'OK', 'Could be better', 'Could be better', 'Awesome', 'Awesome', 'YES!', 'YES!', 'Whatever'), Timestamp = as.POSIXct(c('2015-07-05 00:00', '2015-07-04 02:00',
                                      '2015-04-07 09:00', '2015-04-06 17:00',
                                      '2015-08-08 01:00', '2015-08-07 13:00',
                                      '2015-07-10 03:00', '2015-07-09 19:00',
                                      '2015-03-20 03:00', '2015-03-19 13:00',
                                      '2015-04-19 01:00')), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df %>% arrange(Feedback, Timestamp) %>% group_by(Feedback) %>% slice(1)
```

Alternatively, if you want to use some sort of a time delta threshold, you can use a condition like this with `filter`:

```
df <- df %>% arrange(Feedback, Timestamp) %>% group_by(Feedback) %>% filter(n() == 1 | as.numeric(difftime(max(Timestamp), min(Timestamp), units = 'mins')) < 60)
```

If you want to compute time deltas, here is how you would do it. As you can see, they are above 60 minutes threshold I used as an example above:

```
df <- df %>% arrange(Feedback, Timestamp) %>% group_by(Feedback) %>% summarise(timedelta = as.numeric(difftime(max(Timestamp), min(Timestamp), units = 'mins')))
df
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

         Feedback timedelta
            (chr)     (dbl)
1         Awesome       480
2 Could be better       720
3  Great service!      1320
4              OK       960
5        Whatever         0
6            YES!       840
```

UPDATE: Based on the comment below, to retain the first occurrence always, use the following:

```
df <- df %>% arrange(Feedback, Timestamp) %>% group_by(Feedback) %>% mutate(Timedelta = as.numeric(difftime(Timestamp, lag(Timestamp), units = 'mins'))) %>% filter(is.na(Timedelta) | Timedelta > 60) %>% select(-Timedelta)
```

I am creating an additional column and unselecting it to keep things a bit easier to understand. There is a way to combine the expressions into the filter itself, which gets a bit complex.

Comment: Thanks, the filtering with time delta is a great idea. But when I try your example all feedbacks except 'whatever' is removed?

Comment: That is because all time deltas are outside of 60 minutes. Change the data and filter condition to see the idea in action. You will need to tune to fit your need.

Comment: I understand, but is there a way to filter based on time delta while also guaranteeing that at least one of each unique feedbacks will be kept in the new df?